# Подгрузить карту, удалить карту

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Есть две кнопки показать результаты: "На карте" и "Списком". Как сделать так чтобы при клике на "Списком" удалялась карта, потом по клику на "На карте" подгружалась?

```
$("body").on("click", ".search_show_map", function(){
$("#result_search").html('<div class="search_result_map" id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>');
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
initMap(); });

$("body").on("click", ".search_show_list", function(){
$("#result_search").html(""); });
```

По клику на "На карте" подгружается, после клика на "Списком" пропадает, а вот потом по клику на "На карте" - карта не подгружается:(

Comment: Может лучше не удалять карту, а просто прятать ее.

Comment: потому что ее надо заново инициализировать функцией initMap()